# How does definition foo(*, a=1) in python match the formal 'argument list' in documentation reference?

Tags: python, python-3.x, grammar

I've been studying `*args` and `**kwargs` in python recently and I've come across that in python 3 one can use bare `*` as in the example from the title to indicate that no positional arguments are allowed after it.

The problem is that I don't see how it matches the formal definition or 'argument list' [in reference](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/expressions.html#calls). 
There is a following definition of argument list:

```
argument_list        ::=  positional_arguments ["," keyword_arguments]
                        ["," "*" expression] ["," keyword_arguments]
                        ["," "**" expression]
                      | keyword_arguments ["," "*" expression]
                        ["," keyword_arguments] ["," "**" expression]
                      | "*" expression ["," keyword_arguments] ["," "**" expression]
                      | "**" expression
```

The only way I see it to be valid is for `expression` to be empty, but I couldn't see how it can happen.

In case we assume that `expression` can be empty then the following definitions should be valid:

```
def foo(*)
def bar(*,**kwargs)
```

Those definitions don't make sense since `*` requires keyword arguments after it.

So I would appreciate any clarifications on the subject. What do I miss? Or is the above BNF not quite correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The part of the grammar you're looking at describes function *calls*. And a bare `*` is indeed invalid in a function call.

The [function definition grammar](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) is in another part of the language reference. These productions are relevant:

```
parameter_list ::=  (defparameter ",")*
                    ( "*" [parameter] ("," defparameter)* ["," "**" parameter]
                    | "**" parameter
                    | defparameter [","] )
parameter      ::=  identifier [":" expression]
defparameter   ::=  parameter ["=" expression]
```

Note that here, `parameter`s and `defparameters` are optional after after the `*`.

The error that complains about `def f(*)` and `def f(*, **kwds)` does not come from the grammar. It's legal as far as the grammar is concerned, and is parsed successfully. Only [during AST generation](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/4343dfaca8e2/Python/ast.c#l1332) this is detected and flagged as error. This isn't the only syntactical constraint that isn't handled in the grammar.

Comment: Thank you, I see what I missed now. But shouldn't this definition accept my last two examples: `def foo(*)` and `def bar(*, **kwargs)`? In other words this definition doesn't require bare `*` to be followed by named arguments. And the interpreter reports an error in case of the above examples

Comment: @Phoenix Good point. I'd say this definition should accept those examples, but maybe I'm mistaken. I can't find anything prohibiting it in the [real, official grammar](http://docs.python.org/3.3/reference/grammar.html) either. Maybe I forgot how to read context-free grammars, or this is one of the restrictions enforced not by the parser but by the compiler.

Comment: Thank you! I wonder why did the constrain appear in AST generation instead of the grammar. I suppose it could be included in the grammar by explicitly writing several cases which include `*`